# Is it possible to show errors in silent install in windows

Tags: wix, silent-installer, wixstdba

I have a created an installer using WiXStandardBootstrapperApplication. The intention is to run it silently and I do that using the /quiet flag and it runs silently just fine. The way it runs is, as soon as I enter the command on the command prompt the control returns to the command prompt instantly and the installation happens at the background. So if there are any errors or even in the case of Success, I don't know whether it completed fine or for what reason it failed. In linux, I can run a command silently and the console will show the progress of what are the things that it is doing. Can I do something similar in Windows? I initiate the command and the logs are displayed on the console or at the very least a Success or Failure message is shown on the console window before it stops the execution.

I am aware about the messages being logged in the log file but wanted something to come on the console itself. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the bootstrapper have a -passive option that shows progress?  And errors too I believe.

Comment: @PhilDW, with the -passive option the progress bar will be shown. My use case is that no UI should be shown. Text to be shown on the console window only on which the command is executed.

Comment: Windows Installer isn't a console app - it doesn't feedback to a console window.  I think you're out of luck. Why the console?

Comment: To inform the user that an error has occured or the installation is successful.   The user will issue the command from the command prompt with the /quiet flag but once the user does that the control returns to the console and the user doesn't know whether the installation completed, was it successful or an error occured.

Answer (score 0):

The point of /quiet switch is to have a silent installer. That contradicts the requirement to show any UI. If the installer encounters any errors, it will return exit code other then 0. Details about the failure are in setup logs.

WiX does not do any console logging.

Comment: So there is no way to inform the user that an error has occurred other than the user have to take the step of getting the error from something like GetLastError or something? I just want to inform the user that error has occurred or the installation was successful.